# How to prevent MySQL Create View from corrupting Geospatial function names?

Tags: mysql

Create View on MySQL seems to generate invalid function names when geospatial functions are included in the view (MySQL is running on Amazon EC2 / Amazon Linux);

```
mysql> create view test as select point(1,1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'wordpress.test' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
mysql> show create view test
    -> ;
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| View | Create View                                                                                                                      | character_set_client | collation_connection |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| test | CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`eric`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `test` AS select `st_point`(1,1) AS `point(1,1)` | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> drop view test;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The problem appears to be that st_point is not a valid MySQL function;

```
mysql> select st_point(1,1);
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION wordpress.st_point does not exist
```

Question is, why is this happening, and how do I stop it?

The following is a list of packages installed on the computer which is experiencing the problem;

```
sudo yum list installed | grep mysql
mysql-config.x86_64                   5.5.51-1.11.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql56.x86_64                        5.6.32-1.16.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql56-common.x86_64                 5.6.32-1.16.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql56-devel.x86_64                  5.6.32-1.16.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql56-embedded.x86_64               5.6.32-1.16.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql56-errmsg.x86_64                 5.6.32-1.16.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql56-libs.x86_64                   5.6.32-1.16.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql56-server.x86_64                 5.6.32-1.16.amzn1            @amzn-updates
php70-mysqlnd.x86_64                  7.0.9-1.14.amzn1             @amzn-updates
```

A similar computer with an older mysql package doesn't exhibit this issue - but I need the newer version of MySQL to access new geospatial functions.

The same test on the older computer;

```
mysql> create view test as select point(1,1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+---------------------------+
| point(1,1)                |
+---------------------------+
|              ??      ??   |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create view test;
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| View | Create View                                                                                                                 | character_set_client | collation_connection |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| test | CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`eric`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `test` AS select point(1,1) AS `point(1,1)` | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop view test;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The packages on the older computer;

```
sudo yum list installed | grep mysql;
mysql.noarch                          5.5-1.6.amzn1                @amzn-main   
mysql-config.x86_64                   5.5.51-1.11.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql-devel.noarch                    5.5-1.6.amzn1                @amzn-main   
mysql-server.noarch                   5.5-1.6.amzn1                @amzn-main   
mysql55.x86_64                        5.5.51-1.11.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql55-devel.x86_64                  5.5.51-1.11.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql55-libs.x86_64                   5.5.51-1.11.amzn1            @amzn-updates
mysql55-server.x86_64                 5.5.51-1.11.amzn1            @amzn-updates
php-mysql.x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1             @amzn-updates
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE: This issue has been [verified](https://bugs.mysql.com/?id=82751) as a bug in MySQL version 5.6.10+**

Comment: It looks like they definitely broke this in 5.6 (possibly in `sql/item_geofunc.h`).  Possible workaround is to use `GeomFromText()`: `CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)') AS my_point;`. This behaves correctly, returns a `POINT` as evidenced by the fact that the `X()` and `Y()` functions correctly extract the inner values from the result of the view..

Answer (score 0):

Yep as @Michael mentioned `GeomFromText` works as of 5.6.27.

**If you need to interpolate lat/lng columns into the `Point()` then:**

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `vw_some_table` AS
  SELECT
    id,
    name,
    lat,
    lng,
    status,
    GeomFromText(concat('point(',lng,' ', lat,')'))
  FROM vw_some_table;
```

Note the concat usage.

**or as in your example:**

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `vw_some_table` AS
  SELECT
    id,
    name,
    lat,
    lng,
    status,
    GeomFromText('point(1 1')
  FROM vw_some_table;
```

Very surprised they have not yet fixed such a critical bug... regardless of it working in 5.7.x

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-point-property-functions.html